# C# Virtual Key Code for @ Symbol

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard

Iam looking for the Virtual Key code for the @ Symbol. 
I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation, but I cant find the Key Code for the @ Symbol.

Can anyone help me? 
Thank you.

Comment: `@` isn't a key. You will need to mimic the shift being held down and send in the 1 key. "How" is too broad unless you update your question with how you are currently working with the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no **@** key on a keyboard. We have keys **Shift** and **2** that being pressed together give us **@**.

Comment: How about the french keyboard layout? Ctrl+Alt+2, how to decide which is best?

Comment: Just be aware that this is not applicable for all keyboard layouts

Answer (score 0):

You could check if they press Shift and 2